# Ripple effect is not working on Mac browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm using a ripple effect from a bootstrap library, however I'm getting a weird issue I never seen before. The effect is working fine for me on Chrome (Mac). However, on safari and Firefox (59.0.1, Mac) the effects do not work.

Strangely, the effect works on FireFox for windows, IE, and Chrome for windows.

I'm not sure what is wrong because it has all the web kit properties for these browsers.

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/u3qde8hx/2/

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: royalblue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
    transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
        -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
        transform: scale(0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(25, 25);
        -moz-transform: scale(25, 25);
        -ms-transform: scale(25, 25);
        -o-transform: scale(25, 25);
        transform: scale(25, 25);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(40, 40);
        -moz-transform: scale(40, 40);
        -ms-transform: scale(40, 40);
        -o-transform: scale(40, 40);
        transform: scale(40, 40);
    }
}

button:focus:not(:active)::after {
    -webkit-animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
    -o-animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
    animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}

button:focus{
    outline: none;
}

<p>If you are using FireFox or Safari (Mac versions), this ripple effect will not work for you. It works on PC browsers and Chrome for Mac.</p>
<button>Ripple</button>
```

Comment: I can't find any CSS specification for a ripple effect. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that clicking on a button in Safari and Firefox in OS X doesn't cause the button to become focused, so your animation is not being triggered:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

I tested your code adding this bit of jQuery to force a focused state on a button click, in Safari, and it worked for me:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3qde8hx/28/

Alternatively, it looks like you can accomplish this in Firefox (at least on 59.0.1) and Safari (10.1) on OS X if you replace your button with an anchor tag, but you have to make sure to set a tabindex.

https://jsfiddle.net/u3qde8hx/36/